# Is it possible to turn a monster into a humanoid without giving them average physical ability scores?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, races, ability-scores

*Savage Species* lists some rituals through which a creature can--in one example given--transform from an ogre into an elf.

If nothing else, it's an interesting and evocative idea: a 6th level ogre barbarian who tires of racial prejudices and transforms into an elf. His RHD disappear, and he becomes a 6th-level elf barbarian. His lower effective level means he can no longer travel with ECL ~12 parties, but he decides to do it anyway. <sub>Heck, maybe he did it partly because he was tired of that +2 LA that *Savage Species* likes to pretend isn't a big deal.</sub>

Unfortunately, losing all those hit dice is far from the worst thing that happens to him. Doing any of the book's major rituals means his physical ability scores become, at best, 11/13/9. Considering his ogre-born mental scores aren't picking up much slack either, this is pretty much unacceptable for a barbarian in all but either very silly or very gritty games.

Is there any printed way around this, or to compensate for this beyond things like *wishing* for inherent bonuses and equipping magic items (which any high level barbarian is going to get anyway, so the transformed elf barbarian still finishes with noticeably poor scores)?

That all is to say, is there a way for a 6th-level ogre barbarian to become a 6th-level elf barbarian with a base strength score of at least 12 *and* base constitution at least 10? "Base" meaning: not accounting for non-permanent or inherent bonuses

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119145/discussion-between-fectin-and-hey-i-can-chan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rebuilding rules from *Player‘s Handbook II* also offer a way to change your race (p 198).  Compared with the *Savage Species* ritual rules, race rebuilding works quite differently. Most of all, it is nothing a player can just do, it‘s rather something a DM conceives as part of an adventure, tied to a special place or a quest the party has to fulfill.

Racial rebuilding replaces racial HD and LA with class levels (or vice versa) so that the effective character level of the PC stays the same. So a 6th level Ogre barbarian (with an ECL of 12) who loses their 4 RHD and two LA would become a 12th level Elf barbarian (or some other ECL 12 character).

You **keep your original ability scores**, but you have to recalculate them using the modifiers of your new race while eliminating the modifiers of your old race.

> Each time your character completes a rebuild quest, you can change his
> race. First, remove all racial traits (including ability score
> modifiers) granted by your character’s original race. Then add all the
> racial traits and ability score modifiers from the new race.

An Ogre‘s ability modifiers are: +10 Strength, -2 Dexterity, +4 Constitution, -4 Intelligence, -4 Charisma; an Elf gets +2 Dexterity, -2 Constitution. For a character who changes from Ogre to Elf this would sum up to -10 Strength, +4 Dexterity, -6 Constitution, +4 Intelligence, +4 Charisma.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely not the RAW answer, but I would highly recommend that if this section of Savage Species is used, simply calculate the bonuses/penalties for the original race, reverse them, then apply the resultant ability scores to the target race. One starts with a weak ogre? The end result will be a weak elf. In other words, make the end result care about the starting components. Normalize the stats to the 3d6 stats, then apply the new race's penalties/bonuses accordingly.

Savage Species has many shortcomings and oversights. I do not think it is possible to successfully integrate that book into a campaign without house ruling aspects of it to avoid both breaking the game and making characters useless.

Answer (score 0):

The ninth level spell *Awaken Construct* and the fifth level spell *Awaken* both grant mental ability scores, the former to a construct, the latter to a plant or animal. Oddly, neither perform a check on the creature's mental stats prior to applying their effect, only creature type.

Since either spell grants a variable amount of dice for certain stats, these spells could technically be Maximized or Empowered, if you could obtain a high enough spell slot to cast the adjusted spell with....

For a very rich character, a multi step set of rituals might accomplish the desired end result, however as this sort of planning might be considered as requiring mega-knowledge of how spells work and affect creatures (ie: in-world knowledge of stats and how spells change them), some DMs might not allow this. On the other hand, an NPC who has performed enough humanoid experimentation to become aware of the effect that, "sometimes really smart creatures come out as results of my experiments," may or may not exist in the DM campaign world(s), and sounds like a major quest on top of some interesting roleplaying attempting to negotiate with the (trustworthy?) NPC....

Comment: Does this realy answer the question? Question is about physical abilities, and this answer (and Awaken line, specifically) is about mental abilities.